# When a .NET process Main Thread finishes, what happens with the other currently executing Threads?

Tags: .net, multithreading

When a .NET process Main Thread finishes, what happens with the other currently executing Threads? What if they have allocated unmanaged resources that must be disposed before they stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the other threads have [Thread.IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) set to true, they will exit immediately.  Otherwise the application will keep running (invisibly, if it is a WinForms or WPF application).

If the other threads have unmanaged resources, those will usually be closed/released by the OS when the process exits (file handles, etc.  There may be exceptions to this rule that I am not familiar with).  It is still preferable to release those resources manually when you detect the fact that the application is exiting.

Comment: 'It is still preferable to release those resources manually when you detect the fact that the application is exiting.' why?  If the OS is going to do it anyway, why duplicate the effort unless it's absoultely necessary, (and often fail to do so effectively/correctly).

Comment: @MartinJames because when the process exits, those unmanaged resources are going to be cleaned up by the OS with ***extreme prejudice***. Files that you are in the middle of writing may be left in an inconsistent state, network streams may be closed without notifying the other side, etc. You generally want to know when the process is ending and attempt to save terminal state in a meaningful way.

Comment: @ChrisShain - files and network connections are closed - all my clients show an immediate TCP disconnect if I close my servers with extreme prejudice. I keep perisitent state in the main thread and save it there before exiting, as for any data the other threads - tough:)  The miserable alternative is messy, awkward, difficult-to test thread-signaling code that may, or may not, work on all OS, all core configurations and all blocking calls.  Most of my apps shut down immediately, every time, on all OS and all core configs because all the threads are terminated solely by the OS.